# score validation behaves abnormally in Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel

In my Laravel-5.8 application I have this code:

```
public function findScore(Request $request)
{
    $userCompany = Auth::user()->company_id;
    $userEmployee = Auth::user()->employee_id;
    
    $identities                     = DB::table('identity')->select('id')->where('company_id', $userCompany)->where('is_current', 1)->first()->id;      

   $weightedscore = 0;
   $weightedscore = DB::table('goals')->select(DB::raw("IFNULL(SUM(weighted_score),0) as weighted_score"))->where('identity_id', $identities)->where('employee_id', $userEmployee)->where('parent_id', $parentid)->whereNull('deleted_at')->first();
   $weightedscorex = 0;

   $maxscore = DB::table('goal_types')->select('max_score')->find($child->parent_id);

    return response()->json([
        'maxscore' => $maxscore->max_score,
        'weightedscore' => $weightedscore->weighted_score,
    ]);        
}
```

Route:

```
Route::get('get/findScore','GoalsController@findScore')->name('get.scores.all');
```

view (create.blade.php)

```
          <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label"> Goal Type:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
              <select id="goal_type" class="form-control @error('goal_type_id') is-invalid @enderror" name="goal_type_id">
              <option value="">Select Goal Type</option>

                @foreach ($categories as $category)
                @unless($category->name === 'Job Fundamentals')
                  <option hidden value="{{ $category->id }}" {{ $category->id == old('goal_type_id') ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $category->name }}</option>

                  @if ($category->children)
                    @foreach ($category->children as $child)
                    @unless($child->name === 'Job Fundamentals')
                      <option value="{{ $child->id }}" {{ $child->id == old('goal_type_id') ? 'selected' : '' }}>&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ $child->name }}</option>
                    @endunless
                    @endforeach
                  @endif
                  @endunless
                @endforeach
              </select>

    <input type="hidden" id="max_score" class="form-control" >
    <input type="hidden" id="weighted_score" value="0" class="form-control" >


          <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label"> Weight(%):<span style="color:red;">*</span></label> 
              <input  type="text" name="weighted_score" id="total_weighted_score" value="{{ old('weighted_score', $goal->weighted_score) }}" placeholder="Enter weighted score here" class="form-control @error('weighted_score') is-invalid @enderror" max="120" onkeyup="checkScore(this.value)">
            </div>
          </div>  

    <div class="card-footer">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
    </div>
```

Javascript

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).on('change', '#goal_type', function() {
            var air_id =  $(this).val();

            var a = $(this).parent();
            var op = "";
            
            $.ajax({
                type: 'get',
                url: '{{ route('get.scores.all') }}',
                data: { 'id': air_id },
                dataType: 'json',      //return data will be json
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data.maxscore);
                    console.log(data.weightedscore);
                     $('#max_score').val(data.maxscore);
                     $('#weighted_score').val(data.weightedscore);
                },
                error:function(){

                }
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function checkScore(value){
            let max_score = $("#max_score").val();
            let weighted_score = $("#weighted_score").val();
            let sumValue = parseInt(weighted_score) + parseInt(value);

            if (sumValue > max_score) {
              alert("sum value is greater than max score");
              $("#total_weighted_score").val('');
              return false;
            }
        }
    </script>
```

On select dropdown change using id="goal_type", I loaded the max_score of the selected goal type.
onkeyup="checkScore(this.value)" is used to validated if the accumulated weighted score is greater than max_score. If yes, then it raises an alert:

> alert("sum value is greater than max score");

This works very well in most of the cases. However, I found out that the validation is unstable. At times it doesn't work. It raises the alert even when the accumulated weighted score is less than max_score
The issue happens at various scenarios. But at times when a user tries to enter value into the text input without selecting the dropdown.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Can you explain the "various scenarios" please :)

Comment: @KurtFriars - Ideally the validation should be implemented when the dropdown is selected on change, and then the users types into the text input. 1. But if the user did not select the dropdown onchange and then types into the textinput, the alert pops up which shouldn't be

Comment: did the solution below work out for you?

Comment: @KurtFriars - Problem solved. Thanks a lot

Comment: No problem! Glad to help.

Comment: @KurtFriars - Can you help me out for edit blade. This one is for create.. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't necessarily an optimal solution, but should solve your problem. If the ajax has not returned your values yet just initialize them in a way that they wont trigger your error.

```
function checkScore(value) {
    let max_score = $("#max_score").val();
    max_score = max_score ? parseInt(max_score) : Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER;

    let weighted_score = $("#weighted_score").val();
    weighted_score = weighted_score ? parseInt(weighted_score) : 0;
    
    let sumValue = weighted_score + parseInt(value);
    
    if (sumValue > max_score) {
        alert("sum value is greater than max score");
        $("#total_weighted_score").val('');
        return false;
    }
}
```